# What are chances of AMS->TLV seats to become available at the last minute during coming week?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, ams, short-notice, tlv

I've had the experience before of buying a last-minute ticket from AMS to TLV (it was an indirect flight via Turkey, but never mind) - bought in the morning, flown at noon. I'm going to be taking that route again in a few days, but the problem is I can't say exactly when, while at the same time it might be difficult to delay the trip. Now, I'm seeing flights which I expect to be available to me suddenly no longer appearing on sites like kayak.com - so I suspect they might be full.

Is there a good chance such seats will re-appear at the last moment - on the day of the flight, during this time of the year (specifically, Monday or Tuesday of next week)? If so, will they be at an inflated price (exploiting people's urgency), or a reduced price (to ensure flights are filled up)?

I realize this might be difficult to answer, but if you have comparable relevant experience (whether similar or not), please share.

Comment: Airlines are very good at matching availability to demand now. Getting bumped is a rarity compared to 20 years ago. It is also peak travel season in Europe, and filling planes is not a problem, only how much money you will make. All this suggests if any seat becomes available it is because the airline can sell it for a very high price.

Comment: You might try searching the airline's site directly, to see if those flights really are full, or if Kayak is just not showing them for some other reason.